# How to perform delayed selector safely iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, nstimer

In `viewDidAppear` I show a popup to users after 3 seconds. What if user navigates to another `viewController` after timer begins. The selected function will try to execute & show popup when superview is no longer on screen. App does not crash or throw any errors but I want to confirm this is safe. Should I set a `BOOL` and assert `isCurrentView` is `YES`, within selector method?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showPopup) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5];
}
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code (as text, no pictures).

Comment: @rmaddy added some code. the actual method just animates some constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `viewDidDisappear`

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated];       
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(showPopup) object:nil];
}
```

Comment: I updated question with code. I'm not using a timer object.

Comment: @Anonymous add a NSLog inside the function and make the scenario to check whether called or not

Comment: Yeah it gets called when I segue to another viewController. I tried adding the following: `BOOL isCurrentView = [self.tabBarController.selectedViewController isEqual:self];` to check as a condition but it returns nil even though I'm using a `TabBar`.

Comment: Honestly, the popup should be shown on top of any view, not just the home tab, but since the home tab is the first view after on-boarding I added custom view there.

Comment: keep in mind instances of tabBar are not deallocated until parent tab deallocated , when you switch tabs viewDidappear is called if the controller is tapped before (initated )

Comment: Just found a work around by checking the following condition: `BOOL isCurrentView = (self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window && self.parentViewController != nil);`, But your answer seems better/more consistent with my implementation.